# Java - Passing arguments as key value pairs during programm start alternative

Tags: java, arguments

I hope someone can help me with this one... It's kind of a rookie question, but unfortunately I'm kind of stuck right here.

Currently I'm starting my java application like (cmd):

Now this is the calling part after all the classpath stuff.

*%JAVA_HOME%bin\java.exe -cp %CLASSPATH%;%SCRIPTROOT%jar* -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M view.Main **C:\temp\MyDatabase** **c:\temp\MyFile.xml***

First arg:
C:\temp\MyDatabase

Second arg:
C:\temp\MyFile.xml

```
public static void init(String[] args){

    try {
        mydatabase = args[0];
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        myfile = args[1];
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

Now in this case the order of the arguments is relevant.
With only two arguments this might be just fine, but what am I supposed to do, if I have like 10 arguments and some of them were optional? That would be a problem, right?

What if I do something like this:
%JAVA_HOME%bin\java.exe -cp %CLASSPATH%;%SCRIPTROOT%jar* -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M view.Main **database:/C:\temp\MyDatabase** **myfile:/c:\temp\MyFile.xml**

Now within my code the order would not matter anymore, because I have like a "key-value pair" of arguments and the key identifies the actual "use" of value. This works, but it don't feels right.

Is there a better way of doing this?
Maybe like **java.exe** does it with **-cp**? If yes, how can I implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: Might be overkill for simple programs, but maybe you can look at libraries like [JCommander](http://jcommander.org)

Comment: You can also use system properties: `java -Dfoo=bar -Dbaz=glop view.Main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need java.util.Properties.
Pass them to java process adding `-D`:

```
java -jar my-app.jar -Dfile=C:\temp\MyFile.xml -Ddatabase=C:\temp\MyDatabase
```

Order now does not matter. Get you args inside with System.getProperties() static method, it also has its satellites `System.getPropery(String key)` and `System.getPropery(String key, Object default)`.

For advanced options take a look at [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) and libs like such.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: next step would be to find out which arguments are implemented like windows does with e.g. /? after the command, but I think that's another issue.

Comment: @paul-auerbach please, accept the answer if you're satisfied with solution)